# I am trying to integrate Javascript plugin in Angular 4 but has some issues

Tags: angular

Basically I want to beautify my response Json and I am using jquery jjson plugin to do this job in angular 4

1. I have included `"jquery": "^3.2.1"`, in `package.json` and also included  scripts location in `angular-cli.json` as below

   ```
   "scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
               "./assets/js/jjsonviewer.js"],
   ```
2. Also imported `JJViewerComponent` in `app.module.ts { JJViewerComponent } from './jjviewer/jjviewer.component'`;
3. In my `header.component.ts`, I have imported angular core, declared variables `(declare var $; declare var jJsonViewer: any;)` and used the plugin function to process my response

   ```
   this.asset = $('#response').jJsonViewer(this.data.response, {expanded: true});
   ```

But it is throwing the below error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: $(...).jJsonViewer is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).jJsonViewer is not a function

Can anyone help me to fix this? I need to use the same plugin

Comment: Did you try to import the jQuery module in the header.component.ts? import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';

Comment: Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's necessary for troubleshooting. The question should contain all code to replicate the problem. See also https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: After importing jquery i am getting error at the below line $('.response').jJsonViewer(this.data.response, {expanded: true}); ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function